# Which email setting consumes less power, push or poll?

Tags: settings, email, battery

I would expect hourly polling to consume the least power, but I cannot find a conclusive answer on forums. [This post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17081150&postcount=12) says that push is better, but only for Hotmail accounts, which is strange since the default setting for Hotmail is every 30 minutes.

Which of the following *Download new content* setting is best for battery life?

- Push (As items arrive)
- Poll/pull/fetch (every 15, 30 or 60 minutes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to do a bit more testing on a Nokia Lumia 800 running the 12072 firmware.

I did a basic test using the Nokia battery diagnostics application.

I found that when using *as items arrive* the battery discharge would wildly fluctuate between 80-420 mA, with long periods of around 280 mA. Changing to check *hourly* the discharge was reasonably calm at around 80 mA.

In real world usage I found that *as items arrive* would cause cause the phone to enter battery saver mode in less than 24 hours. When using *hourly* I would get over 2.5 days.

Results may vary, but *for me* I get better battery life using polling.

Full details of the test [here](http://row1.info/news/213-blog/windows-phone/281-nokia-lumia-800-battery-life.html) (*disclaimer: my blog*).

Comment: I think it depends on the amount email you receive per day. If you receive not so mutch _items arrive_ should consume less because it doesn't has data traffic.

Comment: Not sure about that as I don't receive that many items  per day (say around 10 emails) and I was getting poor battery life. My basic tests show that more current is used when _as items arrive_ is turned on. Also, I have heard other people say the opposite, that _as items arrive_ consumes less if you get a lot of email. Really need some empirical evidence on this topic.

Comment: Very strange. I do not receive a lot of emails too. Your signal strenght is good in the majority of the time you use the phone? I think if data connection is not so good can compromise battery healthy.

Comment: My signal strength can be a bit spotty at times (either underground or up high), but it was good when I was doing my test.

Answer (score 6):

The Windows Phone OS has been built from the ground up to manage power in a newer, unique way. For one, like you mentioned, a push notification system. This system is designed to circumvent the old way of having to expend power by polling a server.. especially since most of the time there wasn't anything new there. However, not all services offer it at this point and you still have to pop/smtp things.

My outlook (not hotmail) is almost instantaneous, and sometimes my phone gets it before my web-based version. It is a push based email. Win-Win

So "Push" is your best option, *if is an option*. Otherwise, you'll still need to poll a pop3/smtp server.

Comment: I have been using Hotmail with push and the battery last more than when I used 15 minutes pooling. I recomend.

Comment: While I can appreciate what you are saying, it is still conjecture and doesn't disprove the people saying that push uses more juice.

Comment: You can look at it this way. your phone already has a push notification connection. When developers (including email apps) register for a channel, it uses this connection. Whether you choose to use it or not. When hotmail offers push capability, it is using the same system already in operation. A push notification gets sent through that channel. It s a small data packet that tells the email program to then go fetch the email. When you are polling, your phone is constantly checking the server for any changes, *in addition* to your push channel already operating.

Comment: Although this doesnt give you a direct answer, it explains a little on why it uses less energy to wait for a push notification before polling the mail server for the email http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_e-mail#Microsoft_Windows_Mobile_and_Windows_Phone

Comment: Some initial testing seems to indicate that using push consumes considerably more power than polling. Push seems to wildly fluctuate its discharge between 90-400 mA, poll seems to remain steady at around 70 mA +/- 10. Will do some more testing and post an answer. This is on a Nokia Lumia 800 using their diagnostic tool.

Comment: Add me to the list of those that switched to polling after seeing it yielded longer battery life. While "push" may consume less power than polling on Windows Phone, for small enough intervals, you can't choose an interval less than 15 minutes on Windows Phone, which I don't believe reaches that threshold. I increased my battery life about 50% when switching all applicable accounts to polling, on my Lumia 900.

Comment: I do personally have all my non essential email accounts set to polling, the only one I use push for is my outlook. 60 minute polling is going to save you battery over push, it whether you are willing to wait an hour to get a notification for that account :)

Comment: What about IMAP which, with a persistent connection, gets something similar to push?

Answer (score 3):

It has mostly to do with how Mobile Networks work.  Each connection results in the cellular radio being on for 10-15 seconds after the transaction.  If you get over 12 e-mails an hour - polling every 5 minutes is more efficient than push. However, if you only get 1-2 e-mails an hour, push is more efficient.  I blogged on this (with some math to corroborate). http://networkingexchangeblog.att.com/enterprise-business/push-or-poll-how-email-setup-can-save-your-battery-life/

My phone is set to push on evenings and weekends (low volume) and poll during the workday (high volume)

Answer (score 2):

Pull uses less battery power as it checks for new email messages at a (specified) regular interval.

Using "push" email however allows message to arrive on you device virtually instantly. In order for this to work, your phone needs to keep some form of constantly network connection online

Comment: Do you have any stats or usage data to back this up?