# Lumia 800 battery lifetime

Tags: lumia, battery

I have a Lumia 800 and I recently switched provider (and sim card, of course).
I noticed a big drop in the lifetime of the phone's battery after the switch.

It's strange. I give the phone the same usage but it seems the new provider somehow drains more battery.

One night, no Wifi or GPS, drainned 50% of the battery!

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you on Edge or 3G? I ask just to ensure you did not make the change from edge to 3G when shifting the provider. 3G sucks the battery much much faster than edge. If on 3G switch to EDGE, see if it helps.

Comment: From 3G to 3G...

Comment: I have found that using Battery Saving Mode I get a lot more battery life, so I know that my apps that use Background Tasks (or maybe some particular ones) are responsible for greatly reducing battery life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poor reception drains the battery very fast. Is your new providers reception worse?

You should also check your running background tasks *settings->applications->background tasks*. Try disabling all tasks (if any).

If 3G is on while you are sleeping try [increasing the email polling interval](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/554/295) to one hour.

To further rule out connectivity issues, try sleeping with *airplane* mode turned on. My battery remains at near full change in airplane mode overnight.

Comment: I noticed that in some areas where the previous provider had coverage, the new doesn't. That may help explain it, but doesn't explain why during the night the battery is being drained with max network signal. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I expanded my answer to include a few more usual suspects.

Comment: I'm sure you meant 'decreasing the email polling frequency', not increasing.  When you increase a frequency, it happens more often.

Comment: yes you are correct. Fixed.