# Does Activesync's DirectPush lower battery life? Is there any way to improve on that?

Tags: email, battery, exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which email setting consumes less power, push or poll?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/471/which-email-setting-consumes-less-power-push-or-poll)

During my experience as a Blackberry administrator and programmer I learned that any phone that used HTTP extensively (where the TCP socket is left open waiting for a response) drains the battery unnecessarily.

Somehow Blackberry was able to work around this limitation and offer devices that last several days on a charge and still be up to date on email.

After reading [this information on Direct Push](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997252.aspx) it seems that MSFT phones are leaving a socket open, therefore leaving the cellular radio always on in the Transmit & Receive mode.

Do Windows Mobile phones have any "magic" that makes the battery last longer when doing a TCP "long poll"... perhaps turning the radio on or off as needed for Activesync or other long-poll applications?

Comment: This is related http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/471/which-email-setting-consumes-less-power-push-or-poll , I found that on my Nokia push consumed a more power.