# How do I identify why my battery is draining faster than nornal?

Tags: battery

Lumia 920 with Black update, running WP8. Until about a week ago, my phone had good battery life. Now it drains quickly, and the phone is always hot. I don't recall updating any apps, and it's been fine with the Black update for months. What can I do to diagnose what's causing it to drain the battery faster than normal?

Comment: See: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/how-to-resolve-lumia-920-battery-life-problems/1737

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons why the battery life on your phone appears worse, but Windows Phone 8.0 has no mechanism to tell you what's using all the energy.

The Windows Phone 8.1 update ([it should be available for the Lumia 920 soon](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/)) comes with a new built-in app called [Battery Saver](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/phones-and-hardware/battery-making-it-last), this will allow you to track down the problem if it continues.

In the meantime, the general advice is to...

- Disable NFC if you don't use it.
- Unless you're downloading large files or video often, turn off 4G as it will affect battery life.
- [Disable background tasks for apps that you don't use or care about](http://www.wpcentral.com/fixing-problems-background-tasks-windows-phone).
- Disable Bluetooth if you don't use it.

Comment: Thanks.  The odd thing is that I haven't modified what apps I have, and NFC has always been turned off. Switching off Bluetooth seemed to fix things, although Bluetooth wasn't a problem prior to this week