# Microsoft Lumia 950 that has erroneous low storage warnings, poor battery life, gets very warm and will not download phone update 10.0.10586.29?

Tags: update, storage, battery, windows-10-mobile, lumia-950

What should I do to fix a brand new Microsoft Lumia 950 that has erroneous low storage warnings, poor battery life, gets very warm and will not download phone update 10.0.10586.29?

Following is the system information:

```
Model Microsoft Lumia 950
Software: Windows 10 Mobile
Installed RAM: 3GB

Version: 1511
OS build: 10.0.10586.0
Hardware revision number: 2.1.1.2
Radio software version: BO25c4.00131.0001
Chip SOC version: 8892
Screen resolution: 1440x2560
```

If it matters, I am in Australia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use to have the same problem. Then updated the phone to OS build: 10.0.10586.29 and all seems to work fine although the phone gets hot when I am using it while it is charging.

Answer (score 3):

My summary of the referenced links below:

Check your storage available, you need up to 1.5 GB free space. New phones allocate `System & reserved` 4.98 GB of 29.1 GB. You may also have some pre-installed `Apps & games` taking up space (mine was 1.05 GB). If you have plenty of storage space available then you can **ignore the erroneous storage space warnings**.

The poor battery life is related to the phone trying to download the software update. It is not helped by a minor change in the way the back button operates. Previously the back button in Windows Phone 8.1 would close most apps. Now most apps seem to be left running. Hold down the back button to check what apps are running and close them with the `X`. You can check what is consuming the battery in the phone.

**The fix is to download the software update**, however the phone will not update.

The advice is to:

- connect the phone to power
- set up a stable Wi-Fi connection
- cancel or finish store updates / downloads.
- leave the phone untouched for a long time

The above steps did not work for me with repeated attempts over 5 days using both 4G Wi-Fi and 6Mb ADSL Wi-Fi. It always stopped after downloading 3%.

**In the end I had to do a hard reset of my phone.** I chose not to restore the backup and skipped the one drive setup. Then I immediately checked for updates and left the phone connected to Wi-Fi and power. After about 30 minutes (being super curious) I checked the download progress and it was 39%. After another 30 minutes, it had changed to preparing to install updates 12% and moved to 13% (this point will be important to those who have stared at a percentage that never changed). I was concerned that I had "touched" the phone and what that might do to the update process, but it did not seem to matter. The phone makes a sound when the update is finished and needs to restart. Scroll to the bottom of the screen to `Restart now`. Then the phone shows two spinning gears with a progress bar. This is followed by `Almost done... ...and it will be worth the wait` (23 steps). I also needed to reboot twice for my SIM card to be recognised.

All up the process was done in about 2 hours once I gave in to doing a hard reset.

**References:**

[What should I do if I see a low storage error on my Lumia with Windows 10 when trying to download a phone software update?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA144652)

[My Lumia phone does not work or respond as expected](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA141447)

[What should I do if my Lumia with Windows 10 is stuck on 0% progress when trying to download a software update?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA144658)

[Lumia 950 Not Downloading Updates - Low Storage False Indication](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/lumia-950-not-downloading-updates-low-storage/b18b045e-b245-46d4-ba20-1c178095dc81)

[950 XL battery life tips?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12206/18605)

[How can I update my Lumia software (Windows 10)?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA144542)